# tvOS: Invalid Provisioning Profile. This provisioning profile is not compatible with iOS apps

Tags: xcode, tvos

When trying to publish to iTunes Connect via a `altool` for a tvOS app, I'm running into errors.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool --validate-app --file "/path/to/MyApp.ipa" -t ios --username xxx@example.com --password ********
    2015-10-22 09:05:32.175 altool[8567:159593] *** Error: Unable to validate archive '/path/to/MyApp.ipa': (
        "Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=1176 \"Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Invalid Provisioning Profile. This provisioning profile is not compatible with iOS apps..\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Invalid Provisioning Profile. This provisioning profile is not compatible with iOS apps.., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Invalid Provisioning Profile. This provisioning profile is not compatible with iOS apps.., NSLocalizedFailureReason=iTunes Store operation failed.}"
    )
```

All of the provisioning profiles are correct. I'm running Xcode 7.1 GM Build version 7B91b.

When I do this manually through Xcode it works. The same exact script works for iOS, but not for tvOS.

What gives?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve your issue but, just your title puzzles me, tvOs vs iOS, are you sure you simply don't need other povisioning profiles for tvOS?

Answer (score 9):

I've managed to figure out a working solution. You archive as normal but instead of submitting to the store via the organiser create the ipa/pkg file by selecting | Export -> Save For AppStore Deployment | once the ipa/pkg has been created upload it via Transporter (new version of Application Loader, you can get it from the Mac App Store)

In Transporter you just log in, then select the ipa/pkg created using Xcode, and voila! it works.

Comment: I was using the Application Loader I got from iTunes Connect and it identified the ipa file as an iOS App, but the App Loader as started from XCode as you said works :) Strange!

Comment: Let me try this one! I've been submitting since last night and can't get through. It's always detected as iOS App when I use the standalone Application Loader I downloaded somewhere

Comment: Yooooh! It works! Hihi Thanks :D From now on, I'll use the Application Loader from Xcode hehe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a tvOS distribution provisional profile for your tvOS application.

If you're adding your tvOS application to an existing iOS application and want to take advantage of Universal Purchase, then use the same bundle ID for your tvOS application that your iOS application uses.

Comment: Yep, already doing both of those. This all works correctly when doing it manually through Xcode. I filed a bug report with Apple, but have yet to hear back.

Comment: @syvex Have you tried submitting your application through Organizer in Xcode?